# Répétition ou non du pronom "y"

Tags: pronoms, y

> Voici l'invitation dont je t'ai parlé ce matin. Je vais essayer d'y
> aller et y effectuer le séminaire.
>
> Voici l'invitation dont je t'ai parlé ce matin. Je vais essayer d'y
> aller et effectuer le séminaire.

Quelle tournure est correcte ?

Comment: Les pronoms objets se répètent obligatoirement sur chacun des verbes conjoints, oui.

Comment: histoire de répondre à l'esprit de la question, si pas à sa lettre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le premier des problèmes est le sens : on ne va pas à une invitation, ceci étant une action ou le résultat d'une action ; l'action consiste à prononcer les mots de l'invitation ou de les écrire et de les faire parvenir à l'intéressé ; le résultat est peut être le papier sur lequel sont les mots et le privilège dont jouit la personne intéressée après la réception de l'invitation. Je dois dire que l'on trouve cela dans les mémoires de De Gaulle et que le TLFi le mentionne ; cependant, cela ne suffit pas à justifier cet usage.

> (TLFi) J'ai l'intention de me rendre très prochainement à l'aimable invitation du Premier Ministre et de Votre Excellence (DE GAULLE, Mém. guerre, 1956, p. 370)

On peut **répondre** à une invitation, ce qui a deux sens : fournir une réplique orale ou écrite ou bien tout simplement effectuer ce qui correspond à l'invitation.

Les concepts courants associés à une invitations sont donnés dans le TLFi ;

> (TLFi) Accepter, décliner, esquiver, refuser, renouveler une invitation 
> (dictionnaire Académie) rendre une invitation

Lorsqu'ensuite on parle de **faire quelque chose à une invitation** et que la transgression est entièrement consommée on se rend compte que l'on a fait du mot tout autre chose que ce qu'il est ;  on ne peut pas dire « J'étais à l'invitation. », « Je l'ai rencontré à l'invitation. », etc.

Il est nécessaire de se servir de l'objet de l'invitation ; si c'est une invitation à un mariage alors vous pouvez dire « vous *rendre* au mariage » ou « *aller* au mariage ». Dans le cas présent ceci conviendrait ;

- Voici l'invitation dont je t'ai parlé ce matin. Je vais essayer de (me rendre à/de suivre) ce séminaire.

Il semble que « [effectuer un séminaire](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=faire+un+s%C3%A9minaire%2Ceffectuer+un+s%C3%A9minaire&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfaire%20un%20s%C3%A9minaire%3B%2Cc0) » ne se dit pas et « faire un séminaire » signifie « organiser un séminaire », donc cela ne convient pas ; il doit s'agir de « [suivre un séminaire](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=suivre+un+s%C3%A9minaire&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csuivre%20un%20s%C3%A9minaire%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csuivre%20un%20s%C3%A9minaire%3B%2Cc0) ».
Il faudrait donc dire autre chose ;

- Voici l'invitation dont je t'ai parlé ce matin. Je vais essayer d'y répondre et suivre ce séminaire auquel ils m'invitent.

En ce qui concerne la répétition de « y » il n'y a pas d'inconvénient à le répéter lorsque cela est justifié.

- Ce livre est difficile mais je vais  essayer de m'y mettre et d'y trouver les explications dont j'ai besoin. (*Je vais trouver les explications **dans** le livre.*)

Ne pas répéter peut changer le sens légèrement, ce qui parfois n'est pas si important.

- Ce livre est difficile mais je vais  essayer de m'y mettre et de trouver les explications dont j'ai besoin. (*Je vais trouver les explications peut être dans le livre sinon au moyen de ce que le livre m'apprend.*)